# Access result when running mocha programmatically

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I'm using mocha programmatically and want to access the result in my program for later computation.

Currently, I have:

```
var mocha = new Mocha({
  reporter: 'json'
});

files.forEach(file => {
  var path = process.cwd() + '/' + file;
  mocha.addFile(path);
});

mocha.run()
  .on('start', function() {
    // do something
  })
  // ...
  .on('end', function() {
    // I want to resolve the promise with the result generated by mocha:
    resolve(result);
  });
```

However, I never get access to the result reported by the json reporter (Only on command line).
Is there a way to access the result as json in my program? For example, by writing the result to a file an reading it later?

Comment: Isn't the result passed to the `end` event handler?

Comment: No, non argument is passed to the `end` event handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `json` reporter stores its results on the test runner in the field `testResults`. So you can modify your `end` handler to:

```
.on('end', function() {
    resolve(this.testResults);
 });
```

I've tested it and it works. I've figured this by reading the code of Mocha. I've also checked the documentation but I've not seen something pointing to a public API through which to get these results. As far as I know, only the `json` reporter does this.